# Tabbed Menu - each tab as a separate CS file

Tags: c#, tabs

I'm new to C# and have created a basic program.

My "Main menu" is setup with 7 tabs along the top.
I have set up CASE so when the user selects the tab it adds that specific submenu (frmXXXmenu) to the controls.

The issue is

1. Is this correct
2. Now each form will open each click, thus I keep generating instances of the forms (and I can see my process memory increasing!)

   ```
   private void tabmain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string curtab = tabmain.SelectedTab.Name.ToString();
       switch (tabmain.SelectedTab.Name)
       {
           case "tabcollect":
               frmcollectmenu frmcollectmenu = new frmcollectmenu();
               frmcollectmenu.TopLevel = false;
               tabcollect.Controls.Add(frmcollectmenu);
               frmcollectmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
               frmcollectmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
               frmcollectmenu.Show();
               break;
           case "tabpack":
               frmpackmenu frmpackmenu = new frmpackmenu();
               frmpackmenu.TopLevel = false;
               tabpack.Controls.Add(frmpackmenu);
               frmpackmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
               frmpackmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
               frmpackmenu.Show();
               break;


       }
   }
   ```

Etc for 7 tabs.

Am I in the right direction and if so, how do I fix this instance situation?

I was thinking either Dispose when no longer active.. or somehow not creating a new instance when one is already open?

**Second issue**

One of the forms takes about 2 seconds to open (it is showing a chart based on sql).  How can i load this page in the tab when i open frmmain() to start the program and then when i open the tab it will be loaded?
I tried putting

```
frmcollectmenu frmcollectmenu = new frmcollectmenu();
    frmcollectmenu.TopLevel = false;
    tabcollect.Controls.Add(frmcollectmenu);
    frmcollectmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    frmcollectmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
frmcollectmenu.visible = false;
frmcollectmenu.Show();
```

(added the visible part) then i made it visible again when selecting the tab, but it seems it still takes a few seconds and doesnt really work right.

Comment: @YvetteColomb it is compiling, but as they open more instances, the process memory goes up every time.  This is obviously not 'good technique' so I'm learning how to be smarter about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one instance of your forms opened then you should check the Application.OpenForms collection if one of your forms is already referenced there by the system

```
case "tabcollect":
    frmcollectmenu f = Application.OpenForms["frmcollectmenu"];
    if(f == null)
    {
        frmcollectmenu frmcollectmenu = new frmcollectmenu();
        frmcollectmenu.TopLevel = false;
        tabcollect.Controls.Add(frmcollectmenu);
        frmcollectmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmcollectmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmcollectmenu.Show();
   }
   else
        f.Show();
   break;
```

Notice that this works if you leave the name property of the form to its default name (same as the class name of the form)

You can also try to isolate the logic about your open forms in separate methods for each form and implement a dictionary where you store the tab key and the action to execute when the user select that particular tab

```
  // At form global level....
  Dictionary<string, Action> tabActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
  {
     { "tabCollect", runCollect },
     { .....                    },
         so on for other tabs
  }

  // The logic for a particular form (the same are needed for others forms)
  private static void runCollect()
  {
    frmcollectmenu f = Application.OpenForms["frmcollectmenu"];
    if(f == null)
    {
        frmcollectmenu frmcollectmenu = new frmcollectmenu();
        frmcollectmenu.TopLevel = false;
        tabcollect.Controls.Add(frmcollectmenu);
        frmcollectmenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frmcollectmenu.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmcollectmenu.Show();
   }
   else
        f.Show();
  }
```

Now you can remove the switch in your SelectedIndexChanged method and just select the appropriate action from the dictionary statically build at startup time of your main form

```
private void tabmain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curtab = tabmain.SelectedTab.Name.ToString();
    if(tabActions.ContainsKey(curTab))
       tabActions[curTab].Invoke();
}
```

Comment: So then i do a,b,c,d,e for each other form case?
Is there no way to perhaps put BEFORE the case starts "Form open = Application.OpenForms[openfrm];" or something, and then openfrm = Application.OpenForms["frmcollectmenu"];

Comment: You know which form to check only after the switch. You could create a dictionary where the key is the tab name and the value is a function delegate that runs the particular code that you need to create or reshow the particular form. But I don't think it is really a big difference here.

Comment: Thanks i like the method idea, seems a bit cleaner?

Comment: Has some advantages. The central point is the dictionary at the start of the form and you can add new tabs code just adding a new entry there (and the method of course)  without messing with an enormous switch code. Once learned the trick this simplifies the comprension of the code. I should add also that this dictionary approach is how the compiler transforms the switch when certain amount of cases is reached. (not sure about the exact numbers)

Comment: Thanks Steve, appreciated.

Comment: was just on my way to tick :P